# round SVG images on Joomla site do not get displayed in Firefox

Tags: d3.js, svg, joomla, get

I try to display round images in a svg. The purpose of it is to display round profile pictures within a graph (like in Gmail). The square images of the people are stored in a spritesheet (profiles.png) and I use d3.js for dynamically generating the svg.

This is the part of the code for the round images

```
var imgurl = '../../../images/profiles.png';

var svggraph = d3.select("#graph")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);

var imgRadius = 40;
var profilePos = 1;
var numProfiles = 3;

svggraph.append("defs")
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("id", "patternId")
    .attr("height", 1)
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0").append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", imgurl)
    .attr("x", -profilePos*2*imgRadius)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", numProfiles*2*imgRadius)
    .attr("height", 2*imgRadius);

svggraph.append("circle")
    .attr("r", imgRadius)
    .attr("cx", imgRadius)
    .attr("cy", imgRadius)
    .attr("fill", "url(#patternId)");


// to test the imgurl    
svggraph.append("svg:image")
    .attr("id", "testImage")
    .attr("xlink:href", imgurl)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 50);
```

It worked when I tested it in a plain test HTML, it also worked when I integrated it in my Joomla component in Firefox and Chrome. But if there is a GET query in the url (basically as soon as there is a ? even with no parameters), the round image is not displayed anymore. The svg tags in the "live source code" in the developer tools looks the same if there is a "?" in the url or not. It is always displays correct (with or without query url) in Chrome.

So in summary:

- in Chrome -> always works
- in FF "plain" HTML with and without ? in url -> works
- in FF within Joomla without ? in url -> works
- in FF within Joomla with ? in url -> round image not displayed

The test image (#testImage) is always displayed, so the url to the image is apperently correct.

I also tried the same but with clipPath instead of using a pattern, with the same result (not displayed in FF if ? in url and Joomla).

I already did an extensive google search, but the best I could find was this post with the same problem but not an solution.
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=912784

I don't know what else I could try to fix this.

Comment: Is there perhaps more than one element in your page with id "patternId"?

Comment: no, only the one. It has definitely something to do with the query in the url, which probably wouldn't be the case if multiple "patternId" were the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue happening to me for my Joomla 3.6.4 site in Firefox. I resolved it by removing the `<base>` tag from my template. I added this code to my index.php file in my template:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
unset($doc->base);
```

Comment: I had put this issue on hold (just using a drop down form field  instead of links with GET query), I will try your solution when I get a chance

Comment: I'm now on Joomla 3.7 and it seems like the issue is solved, at least I cannot reproduce the behavior anymore